# Python 3.6 Flask restful and Async for loop

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, flask-restful

So, I have flask restful configured with Sqlalchemy which is returning data from the database and I want to process a function call from the returned data asynchronously.

Example

```
def doSomething(id):
 doing tasks and updating to db


Class XYZ(Resource):
 def get():
  getId = dbgetIds()
  for ids in getId:
   doSomething(ids)
```

I want to make the for loop call the function asynchronously because each call takes a lot of time and by the time it reaches the end of the list it ready to update again. Can anyone help?

Comment: You might want to research python threads.

Comment: Theads do sound good. I was thinking celery with redis.